# How to prevent a sub view from drawing until parent view is selected?

Tags: objective-c, nstabview

I have a NSTabView with 3 tabs. I want to prevent the subviews of those tab from drawing until it is selected. How would I go about doing this? I have set up a delegate for the NSTabView but am having trouble figuring out which tab is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem(*i had two views, view1 above view2 and view2's subviews were drawed while a i was dragging view1*)
The way out was to make a tmpView,that contained all subviews and make 
`[tmpView setHidden:YES];` if it wasn't an active view, and switch on visibility when view2 became active.

Comment: that answers part of it, but how do I detect which tab is detected to determine which view to set hidden/unhidden?

Comment: tabState property of NSTabViewItem can be NSSelectedTab, NSBackgroundTab, or NSPressedTab.

Comment: that got it, is there a way to prevent drawing until that after the application has finished launching? or how do I pass the ManagedObjectModel and ManagedObjectContext to the tab view?